# FSharp R.data_frame

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

I am taking some data from a .csv via the .csv type provider and putting it in to a data frame to be used by R.

Here is the import:

```
#r @"..\packages\R.NET.1.5.5\lib\net40\RDotNet.dll"
#r @"..\packages\RDotNet.FSharp.0.1.2.1\lib\net40\RDotNet.FSharp.dll"
#r @"..\packages\RProvider.1.0.3\lib\RProvider.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.10\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"

open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.``base``
open RProvider.graphics
open FSharp.Data.Csv
open System.IO

let data = CsvFile.Load(@"C:\TEST.csv")
let date = data.Data |> Seq.map(fun r -> r.Columns.[3])
let time = data.Data |> Seq.map(fun r -> r.Columns.[10])
let disposition = data.Data |> Seq.map(fun r -> r.Columns.[11]);

let month = data.Data |> Seq.map(fun r -> r.Columns.[4])
let time2 = data.Data |> Seq.map(fun r -> r.Columns.[7])
```

When I try and create the data frame, I get the following exception - regardless of the datatype that I am trying to load:

*System.Exception: No converter registered for type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] or any of its base types*

Here is an example of the DF load.

```
let namedParameters = [
    "month",month;
    "time",time2;]


namedParameters
|> R.data_frame
|> R.plot
```

The thing is - there are int datatypees.  Is it picking up the header?  Do I need to cast?  If so, isn't that what the type provider is for?  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `R.data_frame` overload that you need is the one taking a dictionary of key value pairs. You could either construct this dictionary yourself, or you can use `namedParams` function that is included in the R type provider library.

To avoid confusion, I renamed your list of pairs to `df`. Then you can create a frame like this:

```
let df = 
  [ "month", month
    "time", time2 ]

namedParams df
|> R.data_frame
|> R.plot
```

PS: Is there any reason why are you using `CsvFile` to read the data dynamically, instead of using the [CSV type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) which should (assuming it works for your input) give you nicer and typed data access to the CSV data?